# I want to write condition if all child value from firebase is true(swift)

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm a new at firebase and now i want to write if all values that receive from firebase are true i want to do something.

this is my Database Reatime

```
- date
    -Friday: true
    -Monday: true
    -Saturday: true
    -Sunday: true
    -Thursday: true
    -Tuesday: true
    -Wednesday: true
```

this is mycode

```
_ = Database.database().reference().child("Info/date")
            .observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

                if snapshot.exists() {

                    if let dictionaryArray = snapshot.value as? [String: Bool] {
                        print(dictionaryArray.values)
                        if dictionaryArray.values == true {
                            print("All is true")
                        }else{
                            print("All is not true")
                        }
                    }
                }else{
                }
            })
```

but it have an error on this line 
"if dictionaryArray.values == true {"

it show that

```
Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Dictionary<String, Bool>.Values' and 'Bool'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to reduce the values (your bool flags) to just one flag that tells you whether any of the flags were false.

```
 let allValuesAreTrue = dictionaryArray.values.reduce(true) {
        allPreviousFlagsAreTrue, currentFlagIsTrue in

        return allPreviousFlagsAreTrue && currentFlagIsTrue

 }

 print(allValuesAreTrue)
```

This code will assume that all flags are true, and then will flip the flag to false if any of them is false.

Answer (score 0):

I think `dictionaryArray.values` is `[Bool]` So, try the following code maybe it's work for you

```
var isFalse = false
for value in dictionaryArray.values {
  if value != true {
      isFalse = true
   }
}

if isFalse {
  print("All value is Not True")
} else {
  print("All value is True")
}
```

Comment: Now it print "value is true" 7 times but i want to check if all values are true print "something"